# Cobol - Designating where a file expansion takes place in a field

Tags: cobol

I am expanding a field S9(8)V9(3) to S9(8)V9(4). The problem is that i do not want the output data to display like this:

12345678.123 -> 12345678.0123
I would like it to look like this:
12345678.1203.

How could i do this?

I have not tried much as I am not sure where to begin.

Comment: Just `MOVE` the field with one definition to a field with the other - and you won't get "intermediate" zeros but correct decimal a to b.

To display it later use edited fields like `PIC --------9.9999` where you `MOVE` that again.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why you ant to do this? I would not consider this an *expansion*, since the desired output is a completely different number.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding the picture to add another place after the decimal point would not cause it to display as `12345678.0123`; rather, it would display as `12345678.1230`.

*How could i do this?*

Use `MOVE` statements to separate in parts, then combine the parts. This is accomplished by using automatic truncation to the `PICTURE` clause.

The `MOVE` to `part-1` strips the trailing digit. The `MOVE` to `part-2`, by using the `P` place holder, strips all except the last digit. After, the `COMPUTE` statement combines the parts as needed.

Code:

```
   data division.
   working-storage section.
   01 in-num pic s9(8)v9(3) value +12345678.123.
   01 part-1 pic s9(8)v99 value +0.
   01 part-2 pic svpp9 value +0.
   01 out-num pic 9(8).9(4).
   01 in-disp pic 9(8).9(3).
   procedure division.
       move in-num to part-1 part-2 in-disp
       compute out-num = part-1 + (part-2 / 10)
       display in-disp " -> " out-num
       goback
       .
```

*I would like it to look like this: 12345678.1203.*

```
12345678.123 -> 12345678.1203
```