# COBOL how would i take hex data and insert into a table?

Tags: hex, cobol

I am trying to take data from a copybook and insert it into a table as part of a restructure. I have this data:

> 03  BUD-ACCT-NUM                       PIC S9(8)V999 COMP-3.

I would like to insert it into this table in working storage:

```
03 G1-VALUE.
           05  NUM-1           PIC 9.
           05  NUM-2           PIC 9.
           05  NUM-3           PIC 9.
           05  NUM-4           PIC 9.
           05  NUM-5           PIC 9.
           05  NUM-6           PIC 9.
           05  NUM-7           PIC 9.
           05  NUM-8           PIC 9.
           05  NUM-9           PIC 9.
           05  NUM-10          PIC 9.
           05  NUM-11          PIC 9.
           05  SIGN-1          PIC X.
```

What would be the best way to make this work? Thank you for your answers ahead of time!

Also, for further clarification, this field is going to be expanded 1 and the table will look like this:

```
03 G2-VALUE.
           05  NUMNW-1           PIC 9.
           05  NUMNW-2           PIC 9.
           05  NUMNW-3           PIC 9.
           05  NUMNW-4           PIC 9.
           05  NUMNW-5           PIC 9.
           05  NUMNW-6           PIC 9.
           05  NUMNW-7           PIC 9.
           05  NUMNW-8           PIC 9.
           05  NUMNW-9           PIC 9.
           05  NUMNW-INSERT      PIC 9 VALUE 0.
           05  NUMNW-10          PIC 9.
           05  NUMNW-11          PIC 9.
           05  SIGNNW-1          PIC X.
```

Comment: I had prepared an answer for the previous question, which was deleted before I could post the answer. Please don't do that. It was a complete waste of my time.

Comment: Would you please explain why you're tagging the question as `HEX`?

Comment: @phunsoft - OP viewed the file in hex, posted image links of hex in a deleted question and, perhaps, considered that it had something to do with the problem. https://i.stack.imgur.com/MK7r1.png https://i.stack.imgur.com/z2Jiw.png

Answer (score 2):

Based on the previously deleted code.

```
       03  BUD-ACCT-NUM        PIC S9(8)V999 COMP-3.
       03  BUDNW-ACCT-NUM      PIC S9(8)V9(4) COMP-3.

       03 G1-VALUE PIC S9(8)V9(3) SIGN TRAILING SEPARATE.
       03 REDEFINES G1-VALUE.
           05  NUM-1           PIC 9.
           05  NUM-2           PIC 9.
           05  NUM-3           PIC 9.
           05  NUM-4           PIC 9.
           05  NUM-5           PIC 9.
           05  NUM-6           PIC 9.
           05  NUM-7           PIC 9.
           05  NUM-8           PIC 9.
           05  NUM-9           PIC 9.
           05  NUM-10          PIC 9.
           05  NUM-11          PIC 9.
           05  SIGN-1          PIC X.

       03 G2-VALUE PIC S9(8)V9(4) SIGN TRAILING SEPARATE.
       03 REDEFINES G2-VALUE.
           05  NUMNW-1           PIC 9.
           05  NUMNW-2           PIC 9.
           05  NUMNW-3           PIC 9.
           05  NUMNW-4           PIC 9.
           05  NUMNW-5           PIC 9.
           05  NUMNW-6           PIC 9.
           05  NUMNW-7           PIC 9.
           05  NUMNW-8           PIC 9.
           05  NUMNW-9           PIC 9.
           05  NUMNW-INSERT      PIC 9.
           05  NUMNW-10          PIC 9.
           05  NUMNW-11          PIC 9.
           05  SIGNNW-1          PIC X.

       MOVE BUD-ACCT-NUM TO G1-VALUE
       MOVE NUM-1 TO NUMNW-1
       MOVE NUM-2 TO NUMNW-2
       MOVE NUM-3 TO NUMNW-3
       MOVE NUM-4 TO NUMNW-4
       MOVE NUM-5 TO NUMNW-5
       MOVE NUM-6 TO NUMNW-6
       MOVE NUM-7 TO NUMNW-7
       MOVE NUM-8 TO NUMNW-8
       MOVE NUM-9 TO NUMNW-9
       MOVE 0 TO NUMNW-INSERT
       MOVE NUM-10 TO NUMNW-10
       MOVE NUM-11 TO NUMNW-11
       MOVE SIGN-1 TO SIGNNW-1
       MOVE G2-VALUE TO BUDNW-ACCT-NUM.
```

Answer (score 1):

My understanding, thanks to Bruce Martin, is that you want to convert an S9(8)V9(3) number to an S9(8)V9(4) number with a twist.

You don't want XXX.123 to convert to XXX.1230, which would be the usual result.  You want to convert to XXX.1203.  I'm assuming that you want to switch the digits of the third and fourth decimal places.

One slightly convoluted way would be this WORKING-STORAGE.

```
03  NEW-BUD-ACCT-NUM PIC S9(8)V9(4) COMP-3.
03  NEW-BUD-ACCT-TEMP PIC S9(8)V9(4).
03  BUD-ACCT-NUM PIC S9(8)V9(3) COMP-3.
03  TEMP PIC 9.
03  BUD-ACCT-STRING PIC +9(8).9999.
03  G2-VALUE REDEFINES BUD-ACCT-STRING.
    05 SIGNNW PIC X.
    05 NUMNW OCCURS 8 TIMES PIC 9.
    05 FILLER PIC X.
    05 NUMNX OCCURS 4 TIMES PIC 9.
```

The PROCEDURE DIVISION code would look like this.

```
MOVE BUD-ACCT-NUM TO BUD-ACCT-STRING
MOVE NUMNX(4) TO TEMP
MOVE NUMNX(3) TO NUMNX(4)
MOVE TEMP TO NUMNX(3)
```

These next two lines may or may not work with your COBOL compiler.  These lines follow the four lines given above.

```
MOVE BUD-ACCT-STRING TO NEW-BUD-ACCT-TEMP
MOVE NEW-BUD-ACCT-TEMP TO NEW-BUD-ACCT-NUM
```

Comment: Yeah i am not even sure where to begin with that lol

Comment: would be simpler to use 9(8)V999 sign separate trailing and one array

Comment: @Bruce Martin: I wasn't sure what the OP was trying to accomplish.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc - OP had previously asked https://stackoverflow.com/q/74826379/9170346, then chose a different route. For those who can view deleted questions (not me), the code should be in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74864144/cobol-expanding-hexadecimal.